# password validation with angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

How to implement the password validation by meeting the below conditions with Angular 8:

Password needs to be atleast 8 characters with atleast 1 number and 1 special character in out of 8 special characters !@#$%[]{}

Need to show the messages on the fly when the certain condition not met. So how to implement it.

I have this form with the code below:

```
<form role="form" #heroForm="ngForm">           
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-md-0 control-label"></label>
              <div class="col-md-5">
                <mat-form-field class="full-width">
                  <input required [(ngModel)]="member.password" name="pass" id="pass" type="password" matInput
                    placeholder="Password" min="8">
                  <mat-error>Required</mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-5">
                <mat-form-field class="full-width">
                  <input required [(ngModel)]="member.confirmPassword" name="pass" id="confirmPassword" type="password"
                    matInput placeholder="Confirm password" min="8">
                  <mat-error>Required</mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

Comment: you can do it with validators loke this :

password: ['', Validators.compose([
    Validators.required,
    Validators.minLength(3),
    Validators.maxLength(100)
   ])
   ],
   confirmPassword: ['', Validators.compose([
    Validators.required,
    Validators.minLength(3),
    Validators.maxLength(100)
   ])
   ],

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex validation and on valid regex you can enable the button

Check this link

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/05/use-regex-to-test-password-strength-in-javascript/

Or you can use pattern attribute and set the regex there and set the pattern validation on the password field like this

pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}"

Answer (score 1):

Add pattern at input level pattern="^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&*])(?=.{8,})"

Now there are several ways to do that. If you are using dynamic forms or html level

lets do with FormControl : first instantiate :

```
password= new FormControl();
```

Then put formControl attribute at input level :

```
<input required [formControl]="password" [(ngModel)]="member.password" pattern="^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})" name="pass" id="pass" type="password" matInput
   placeholder="Password" min="8"/>
```

Then show error like below:

```
 <mat-error *ngIf="username.errors?.pattern">Password not valid</mat-error>
```

There other way to do is FormBuilder. Refer the docs.